# Cryptic quote from a press conference

Tags: cryptic-clues

> *(Buzz, expressions of hesitance)* "The United Nations, together with a European nation", repeated USA's leader, "discovered Papuan area for exotic fish" (21)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a cryptic clue with the solution:

> `HUM` [buzz]
>  `UH UM` [expressions of hesitance]
>  `UN` [the United Nations]
>  `UK` [a European Nation]
>  `UN UK` [[last two parts] repeated]
>  `U` [USA's leader]
>  `APUA` [dis-covered "papuan" (i.e. missing its "cover", or outer letters)]
>  `A` [area]
>
>  together forming **HUMUHUMUNUKUNUKUAPUA'A**, the state fish of Hawai'i ([also known as the reef triggerfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reef_triggerfish)).

Comment: What the ... Next challenge: create a cryptic clue with the solution Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch.