# Fairground Disappointment

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

> This Welsh town's northern fair is, after all, very backward: firstly popcorn with lemon; secondly, bloody agility swings; finally, scary clown going away without starting. All agog, very chewy outer layers right now. Selling wares from wardrobes: two ewes, four fifties, inner pants. Outwardly yes, but inward leaping indignation ordered first, and the command to advance was primarily cack-handed.

The answer is one word. (This is inspired by something else, but I'll add a link later; it's [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) for now.)

Comment: Knew this was bound to happen, what with the rot13(uhzhuhzhahxhahxhnchn'n) clue! :P I love this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> Llanfair­pwllgwyngyll­gogery­chwyrn­drobwll­llan­tysilio­gogo­goch, which is the name of a [town in northern Wales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llanfairpwllgwyngyll).

Because

> "Northern fair" = NFAIR, after "all" very backward = LLA, so LLANFAIR so far. "Firstly popcorn with lemon" = PWL. "Secondly bloody agility swings" = LGW. "Finally scary clown going away" = YNGY, so LLANFAIRPWLLGWYNGY so far. "without starting all agog very" = LLGOGERY. "chewy outer layers" = CHWY. "right now" = RN. "Selling wares from wardrobes" = DROB. "two ewes" = "double u" = W. "four fifties" = LLLL. "inner pants" = ANT. We've got LLANFAIRPWLLGWYNGYLLGOGERYCHWYRNDROBWLLLLANT so far. Outwardly yes = YS. ("but" is not used.) "inward leaping indignation ordered first" = ILIO. ("and" is not used.) "the command to advance" = GOGOGO. "was primarily cack-handed" = CH. Put it all together to get LLANFAIRPWLLGWYNGYLLGOGERYCHWYRNDROBWLLLLANTYSILIOGOGOGOCH.

Comment: Aw, just beat me to it as I was writing up the explanation. (You may want to explain what this actually *is*, too -- you don't mention it in your answer.)

Comment: @Deusovi That's the first sentence of my "Because". I can edit to make it clearer.

Comment: Oh, sorry -- by "this" I mean the type of puzzle.

Comment: Correct! [Link to inspiration](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95212/cryptic-quote-from-a-press-conference#comment272401_95213).

Comment: I suppose the next one would have to be [Lake Char­gogg­a­gogg­man­chaugg­a­gogg­chau­bun­a­gung­a­maugg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Chaubunagungamaug)...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman ...as a "hidden word" clue :P